# How can I persist the value of a variable updated when passing it down to a child component in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to pass down the variable `selectedContactId` from a `useState`. I'm console logging the variable in the parent component and it is updating its value and then I'm console logging the prop received in the child component, it is successfully received the updated value, however, then it prints the console log again and the value is set as `undefined`.

I guess it is because it is re-rendering when jumping to the new component, so I've tried different ways to persist it, and what seems more reliable to me is using the `useMemo()` state, and I'm trying to implement it but it is still not working. If is there an easier way to do that, I'd appreciate you sharing that with me.

[Sandox replication of error code](https://codesandbox.io/s/crm-sample-bcpe56?file=/src/components/Contact/ContactTable.jsx)

Here is my code and a screenshot of the console logs.

[image: Console logs track]

ContactTable.jsx

```
const ContactTable = () => {
  const { handleNavigation } = useContext(ContactContext)

  const [selectedContactId, setSelectedContactId] = useState(0);

  const memoizedSelectedContactId = useMemo(() => selectedContactId, [selectedContactId]);

  const isEven = (idx) => idx % 2 === 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    getContactList(currentPage)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-full max-w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-6 pb-10 pl-10 pr-10" >
        <Tittle className="text-2xl font-semibold text-orange-500"> Clientes</Tittle>
        <Table id="table-to-xls">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeader>ID/NIT</TableHeader>
              <TableHeader>OPCIONES</TableHeader>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {contactList?.content?.map((contact, idx) => (
              <TableRow key={contact.map.seq_id} className={isEven(idx) ? "" : "bg-sky-50"} >
                <TableData>{contact.map.id}</TableData>
                <TableData>
                  <BoxSelectorOptions>
                    <SelectOptions
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const selectedValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
                        console.log("Selected Value: " + selectedValue);
                        setSelectedContactId(selectedValue); 
                      }}
                      onClick={handleNavigation}
                    >
                      <option>[Ir a...]</option>
                      <option value={contact.map.id} data-url="/followUp">
                        Seguimiento
                      </option>
                    </SelectOptions>
                  </BoxSelectorOptions>
                </TableData>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        {selectedContactId !== 0 && contactList && ( // Add aditional rendering
          <CollectionPortfolioFollowUps 
            contactIdentifier={memoizedSelectedContactId} 
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactTable
```

CollectionPortfolio.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react'

const CollectionPortfolioFollowUps = ({ contactIdentifier }) => {
  console.log("It was received in CollectionPor contact ID: " + contactIdentifier)  { contactIdentifier, contactList }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Contact ID: {contactIdentifier}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const MemoizedCollectionPortfolioFollowUps = React.memo(CollectionPortfolioFollowUps);

const MemoizedWrapperComponent = ({ contactIdentifier }) => {
  const memoizedContactIdentifier = useMemo(() => contactIdentifier, [contactIdentifier]);

  return <MemoizedCollectionPortfolioFollowUps contactIdentifier={memoizedContactIdentifier} />;
}

export default MemoizedWrapperComponent;
```

In the child component, I've tried to implement also `useMemo` to avoid the re-render and updating the prop value as `undefined`.

Comment: `selectedContactId` is React state, it's effectively already "memoized" by default. Try console logging in a `useEffect` hook in the child component instead of as an unintentional side-effect. You could/should probably remove all the memoization that you are trying to do as the values you are memoized aren't really changing references. They *do change*, but because they are React state it's understood it will trigger a rerender.

Comment: Okay, I have removed all the memoized and I'm trying console logging in a useEffect in the child component but still receiving exaclty the same 4 console.logs, 2 with the new/expected `contactId` of the customer and 2 as undefinied. This is how I'm validating with useEffect: 
`useEffect(() => {
    if (contactIdentifier !== undefined) {
      console.log("It is different of undefined " + contactIdentifier)
    } else {
      console.log("it is undefined" + contactIdentifier)
    }
  }, [contactIdentifier])`

So what do you think could be the reason for changing the value to undefi?

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could take a look at live?

Comment: Well, I've never done a codesandbox demo, I'm trying to do it, it might take me some time, it seems a little tricky as I'm consuming an API with some data, using different classes, so I have to recoding everything but briefly and sumarized. But I'm on it.

Comment: The APIs probably aren't necessary, you can mock the request and response values.

Comment: Well I have succesfully replicated the error I'm getting in the sandbox, the path "/" is the main table, once we click the options dropdown and click `follow-up` it takes us to the component <CollectionPortfolio.jsx/> and send the captured `customer_id` as a prop to that component. This is the link @DrewReese I added it in the post as well, Thanks in advance for checking out: https://codesandbox.io/s/crm-sample-bcpe56?file=/src/components/Contact/ContactTable.jsx

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are rendering `CollectionPortfolioFollowUps` in two places. In the `CollectionPortfolioFollowUps` instance that `ContactTable` renders you pass it a `contactIdentifier` prop. The is the console log with a defined value.

```
const ContactTable = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="....">
        <Table id="table-to-xls">
          ...
        </Table>
        {selectedContactId !== 0 && (
          <CollectionPortfolioFollowUps
            contactIdentifier={selectedContactId} // <-- defined here
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the CollectionPortfolioFollowUps instance rendered on the "/followup" route there is no passed prop. This is the console log with undefined value.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    {/* <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}> */}
    <Route path="/" element={<Contact />} />
    <Route
      path="/followUp"
      element={<CollectionPortfolio />} // <-- no prop passed here
    />
    {/* </Route> */}
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

## Solution

If I'm correct in assuming that the desired behavior is that you want to *pass* the selected `selectedContactId` state value along to the `CollectionPortfolioFollowUps` component rendered on `"/followup"` then I'd suggest passing in route state when navigating.

```
const ContactTable = () => {
  const [selectedContactId, setSelectedContactId] = useState(0);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleNavigation(e) {
    const url = e.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.url;
    if (url) {
      navigate(url, { state: { selectedContactId } });
    }
  }

  return (
    ....
  );
};
```

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const CollectionPortfolioFollowUps = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const {selectedContactId} = state || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ selectedContactId });
  }, [selectedContactId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Contact ID: {selectedContactId}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-persist-the-value-of-a-variable-updated-when-passing-it-down-to-a-chil]

Comment: Beautiful, yes, you were right, that was the right asumption! I wanted to pass the `selectedContactId` when it rendred on "/followup".  It just worked. Understanding what did I do wrong and the cause of the issue changes everything!

Comment: @Rosh343 Great, glad to help. Sounds like your question/issue has been addressed/resolved. Cheers and good luck.